# sorting numbers in digit order - c++

Tags: c++, sorting

The program I'm trying to write is about distributing food by people id.
And I'm using sort method to sort the people by their id. The problem is below:

[image]

result I wanted:

```
9 90
60 90
81 90
3 80
5 80
4 60
72 60
```

But when I sort only id with sort method, it works properly. I'm not sure what the problem is.

And this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Info
{
    int id;
    int weight;
    bool operator < (const Info& val) const {
        return val.weight < weight;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<Info> info_v;
    Info info;
    int childNum = 0;

    cin >> childNum;

    for (int i = 0; i < childNum; i++) {
        cin >> info.id >> info.weight;
        info_v.push_back(info);
    }

    sort(info_v.begin(), info_v.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < childNum; i++)
    {
        cout << info_v[i].id << "\t" << info_v[i].weight << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How do I sort the numbers in digit order? Please give me some idea!

Comment: `std::sort(vector)` from `<algorithm>` is a really good sorting function.

Comment: Pleast post compilable code. You are missing several includes.

Comment: I used sort function and it doesn't sort numbers in digit order@StackDanny

Comment: @user19283043 if you want digit(alphabetic) order, do not read them as number will be more eazy.

Comment: then can I compare those numbers if I read them as string? @appleapple

Comment: @user19283043 If the issue is with sorting, why are you showing all of this code like `IncrementIfFound`, `GetCounter`, etc.  that has absolutely nothing to do with sorting?  Just the struct, add some data, sort, fix what's broken.  In other words, a [mcve], similar to [this](http://ideone.com/tUps5N)

Comment: I edited! please give me some idea @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: You wrote an `operator<` that compares by _weight_, called the default [sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) which uses that for its comparison, and then complained it isn't sorted by _id_. Either provide sort a comparator, or have `operator<` use _id_.

Comment: @Useless I just realised my mistake and fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace the tab '\t' by a single space.

Comment: Funny, but not really helpful as an answer, don't you think?

Comment: Look at what he wants and what he gets.  Then try the change.